# Use nested class of templated class as template template parameter in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, template-templates

In C++, I'd like to use a nested class inside a templated class as template template parameter. For non-nested classes the pattern is:

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
    T a;
    // ...
};

template<class T, template<class ST> class S>
class B {
public:
    S<T> b;
    // ...
};

B<int, A> b;
```

Now I'd like to add a nested class to `A` and use this nested class as template template parameter `S` of class `B`, like this:

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
    class AA {
    public:
        T aa;
        // ...
    };
    // ...
};

template<class T, template<class ST> class S>
class B {
public:
    S<T> b;
    // ...
};

B<int, A> b1;          // ok
B<int, A::AA> b2;      // error
B<int, A<int>::AA> b3; // error
```

I understand that the declarations of `b2` and `b3` are errors because `A::AA` is incomplete and `A<int>::AA` is not a template.

I would like to be able to declare something similar to `b2`. The idea is that `A` and `B` should both use the same class `T`.

I would like to be able to declare a number of classes similar to `A` with individually named sub-classes. Another use of this I can think of are multiple sub-classes of `A` that can be used as template template parameter to `B`.

One workaround I see is to refrain from using individual names on the sub-classes of `A`, use the `b1` declaration (use `A` as template template parameter `S` for `B`) and change the implementation of `B` accordingly (i.e. use `S::AA<T>` instead of `S<T>`):

```
template<class T, template<class ST> class S>
class B {
public:
    S::AA<T> b;
    // ...
};

B<int, A> b;
```

The other workaround I see is to reduce the template template parameter of class `B` to a simple template parameter, and ensure the same `T` by other means.

Is there some other possibility? If yes, how?

**Edit**: Added forgotten `class` in `template` for `B` and changed template template parameter name to `ST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create an template alias:

```
template <typename T>
using innerAA = typename A<T>::AA;
```

and then

```
B<int, innerAA> b42;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82f5b45a3d52d87e)

Comment: Thanks! I guess there is no possibility to avoid another name?

Comment: You may name it `AA`if you want to.

Comment: The `using` directive is what I really was looking for. Don't know why I didn't find it earlier ... thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
    class AA {
    public:
        T aa;
        // ...
    };
    // ...
};

template<class T, template<class ST> class S >
class B {
public:
    S<T> b;
    // ...
};

template<class T> using NestedAA = typename A<T>::AA;

int main()
{
  B<int, NestedAA> b; // ok

  return 0;
}
```

If for any reason you are constrained to C++03, type aliases won't be available to you. You can then replace the "using" statement with the following definition for NestedAA:

```
template<class T>
class NestedAA : public A<T>::AA
{
};
```

Comment: Very nicely done. However, I think I'd prefer a true alias to `AA` rather than a derived type: try `template<class T>
using NestedAA = typename A<T>::AA;` instead.

Comment: Thanks @AndyG, this is a valid remark. I didn't use that because I wasn't using C++11 for my test. The author didn't specify if using C++11 would be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice. Though I'd also prefer a true alias to `AA` as @AndyG.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you *only* want the nested case to work, and since AA itself is not a template you could just drop the template for B's 2nd parameter like so:

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:
    class AA {
    public:
        T aa;
        // ...
    };
    // ...
};

template<class T, class S>
class B {
public:
    S b;
    // ...
};

//B<int, A> b1;          // error
B<int, A<int>::AA> b2;      // ok
```

PS Your original declaration of B needs an extra 'class' to compile on g++ 5.4

```
template<class T, template<class T> class S>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I also thought of doing. Yes, I forgot to add the 'class' in the template statement for B. I'll edit my question.